# How can I block a JComponent from another class?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, jcomponent, filechooser

I am trying to disable a `JComponent` from another class, similar to a modal dialogue. In my case, I'm invoking a JavaFX dialogue from a Swing component; more specifically a [`FileChooser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html). Since, for example, `showOpenDialog` expects an `javafx.stage.Window` as argument, passing the `JComponent` is not an option.

I tried using [`setEnabled(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setEnabled-boolean-) and `setEnabled(true)`, but this has a strange side effect: Upon invoking `setEnabled(true)`, the `JFrame` will be minimized. Invoking `setVisible(true)` solves this but causes the screen to “flash”, because the frame will still disappear for a short time.

The problem only occurs when I'm using a `CountDownLatch` to await the return of the file chooser, which is necessary because otherwise it would return immediately and I wouldn't be able to access the return value.

Here is a SSCCE to reproduce the issue:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");
        JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();

        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.setEnabled(false);

                CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                    latch.countDown();
                });

                try {
                    latch.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                frame.setEnabled(true);
            }

        });
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
}
```

Is there another option to block the component?

Comment: Do you want to block `JFrame` completely (e.g. no scaling) or just block interaction with its content?

Comment: I think the latter would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on this article https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html

The idea is that when `FileChooser` is opened we use custom `GlassPane` that intercepts all mouse events. It's not ideal solution, because you can still minimize, maximize and close underlying `JFrame`.

```
public class MyGlassPane extends JComponent implements PropertyChangeListener {
    public MyGlassPane() {
        CBListener listener = new CBListener();
        addMouseListener(listener);
        addMouseMotionListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        setVisible(((Number) evt.getNewValue()).intValue() == 1);
    }
}
```

```
public class CBListener extends MouseInputAdapter {
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        consume(e);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        consume(e);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        consume(e);
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        consume(e);
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        consume(e);
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        consume(e);
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        consume(e);
    }

    private void consume(MouseEvent e) {
        e.consume();
    }
}
```

With above classes you can put below `FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();` line code like this:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frame.firePropertyChange("disabled", 0, 1);
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            frame.firePropertyChange("disabled", 1, 0);
        });
    }
});

MyGlassPane mgp = new MyGlassPane();
frame.setGlassPane(mgp);
frame.addPropertyChangeListener("disabled", mgp);
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I was thinking about using a glass pane, too. The thing is, as mentioned in my post, I just have a `Component` (so the situation is different than the one in my SSCCE). I suppose I can check whether the component is `instanceof RootPaneContainer` and, in that case, disable it using the glass pane.